# Is there really a way to do seamless page loads, with complex pages, nested AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, event-handling

OK, I spent a whole day trying to revamp my seamless page transition method. Previously I had a simple solution. When a user clicked to go to another page on the website I did a jQuery slideUp on the content and faded the background to match the upcoming page (because each page has its own background). Then I load the new page which starts off in a "slid up" position then it slides down after window.load().

It worked pretty great and avoids any complications because it actually does load the new page. But there is this tiny flicker most of the time right when the new page loads. I thought I could do better than that. I've seen other fancy sites that smoothly fade new pages in and out, why couldn't I do it?

So I totally rewrote things so that the old content is wiped and content from the other page is loaded in with AJAX. Then I also had to load and run scripts that pertain to the new page, including loading items with more AJAX from Flickr and Soundcloud. I actually got it all working pretty good except for one major problem. I can no longer count on window.load() for when to trigger the slideDown. I can't figure out any way to get the slideDown to happen once everything is done.

If I was loading simple static pages I think it would be fine to use the $.load() callback to trigger the slide down. But in my case the pages I am loading are doing further AJAX calls so the page comes in "empty" with just a title or something and then the slide happens and THEN all the pictures from Flickr come piling in, ruining the smooth slide effect.

There were some other disturbing quirks when I jumped back and forth between "pages", so I am wondering if this whole endeavour is just destined for disaster. Maybe I should keep my simple transition method? But then is there some way to minimize the flicker of content when it jumps to the new page?

Comment: This question is extremely broad. "Is it possible"? Well, it probably is, but we can't say for sure without seeing your exact code. Flicker of content doesn't mean much when we can't actually *see* the problem.

Comment: Well there is too much code to bother showing but I have narrowed the problem down to two questions. Are there techniques available so that when you jump between two identical looking pages you can avoid that brief flicker while everything reloads OR is there a way to know when your ajax request has really finished loading when the stuff you requested is itself doing other ajax requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came up with a solution of retrieving a page through an iframe and having a window.load event in the iframe inform it's parent page when it is done loading (which doesn't happen until its ajax requests have all come in) and then appending the content of the iframe into the parent page and deleting the iframe. This wasn't a very efficient solution though and the jquery Flickr plugin was causing errors in IE, so I scrapped the whole iframe thing and loaded the flickr feed with PHP instead. I think this is the way to go. Use server-side code instead of nested ajax calls whenever possible.